# How to Add a Border to a Transparent Body in CustomCoachMarkBodyView - Swift Package Instructions

Tags: swift, swift5

[image]

whenever am trying to add border the arrow and CustomCoachMarkBodyView get different border need to make it into one view and add border

Comment: Show your code please.  It's hard to help if we can't see your current implementation.